# How to convert dd partition image to virtualbox virtual disk?

Tags: virtualbox, dd, forensics

I created a backup from /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda4 partitions using dd. but i did not create a backup from /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda3. How can I convert these 2 backup files from /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda4 namely sda1.img and sda4.img to virtualbox disk and boot the system?

Comment: If you still have the source disk it may be easier to just create an VDI image from the partitions as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/252450/62676).

Comment: @Robert No I only have these 2 files

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I am missing /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda3

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I dont have access to original disk to make a dd images of them. I have only /dev/sda1 which contain grub boot loader and /dev/sda4 which has home folder. sda2 and sda3 had just some files in them and 200GB of free space so i didn't use dd on them.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey create a virtualbox  image that can boot the system without having sda2 and sda3

Comment: Have you successfully managed to mount the files to a directory on your system? (`sudo mount -oloop <FN> <mountpoint>`) if you can do this, you can set the mountpoint up as a virtualbox disc location

Comment: I dont need sda2 and sda3. that is why i didn't create a dd image from them.

Comment: @Mark Yes I can mount it and see the files. but I want to boot the OS.

Comment: @Rembo you need to have a look at the VBoxManage CLI command to create the disk. Something like: `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "</path/to/file>.vmdk" -rawdisk <diskimg.img>` https://mobile.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/using-a-physical-hard-drive-with-a-virtualbox-vm.html

Answer (score 1):

**1. Test the disc image mounts sucessfully**

```
mount -t loop <disc image.img> <mountpoint>
cd <mountpoint>
ls # should show disc image contents as expected
```

**2. Create a VMDK image referencing your disc image**

```
VBoxManage internalcommands  createrawvmdk -filename <vmdk filename>.vmdk -rawdisk <disc image.img>
```

**3. Create a VirtualBox machine**

Select the VMDK file, created in the previous step, as your disc image.

***Alternatives***

Other virtualisation technologies are available. For example, you could also use `qemu` for this task:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276480/booting-a-raw-disk-image-in-qemu

Comment: It is converting but the system is not booting. I got this message: no bootable medium found. system halted!

Comment: Depending on how your disc was set up originally (GPT or MBR), it is likely you are missing the boot data from `/dev/sda`. Make sure you keep backups of the partition before attempting repair http://www.aboutlinux.info/2005/11/how-to-repair-corrupt-mbr-and-boot.html?m=1

Comment: The issue here is that dd image conversion takes a partition image, not a disk image, and creates a disk with the content of a partition, so /dev/sda1 from source ends up on /dev/sda on the target. I wonder how could this be made to restore /dev/sda1 to /dev/sda1 VDI partition.